# Не работает javascript после загрузки контента ajax-ом

Tags: javascript, ajax

На странице реализована подгрузка контактной формы через ajax.
Также на странице используется плагин валидации формы перед ее отправкой.
Без ajax валидатор работает, но при подгрузке формы ajax-ом прекращает работать валидатор.
Подозреваю что проблема в этом куске кода

```
s.prototype.initialize=function(){
  return this.$target
    .on("input",t.proxy(this.change,this))
    .on("focus",t.proxy(this.focus,this))
    .on("blur",t.proxy(this.blur,this))
    .on("hover",t.proxy(this.hover,this))
    .parents("form")
    .on("reset",t.proxy(this.reset,this)),
    this.change(),
    this.hover(),
    this
    },
    s.prototype.hover=function(){
        return isWebkit&&(this.$target.is(":-webkit-autofill")?this.$element.addClass("auto-fill"):this.$element.removeClass("auto-fill")),this}
```

и

```
elements
.on('input change propertychange blur', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this), results;

    if (e.type !== "blur") {
        if (!$this.parent().hasClass("has-error")) {
            return;
        }
    }

    if ($this.parents('.rd-mailform').hasClass('success')) {
        return;
    }

    if ((results = $this.regula('validate')).length) {
        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            $this.siblings(".form-validation").text(results[i].message).parent().addClass("has-error")
        }
    } else {
        $this.siblings(".form-validation").text("").parent().removeClass("has-error")
    }
})
```

подскажите как переделать по такому примеру
 `$(document).on('click', 'element', function () { });`

Comment: "при подгрузке ajax" - где в Вашем коде ajax?

Comment: при подгрузке через ajax нужно обновлять DOM для js, для этого после подгрузки вызывайте ваш код по новой (лучше оформить в функцию, дабы не плодить код).